# Applying CSS to razor helpers

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor

Previously I made my own form using HTML and CSS. I combined CSS classes and ID's to create the desired style. Because of convenience & a suggestion from a Lynda.com video I wanted to take advantage of the Reference Libraries to allow for client-side form validation (using the jQuery Validate library).
Now I am trying to apply my classes and id's to the autogenerated labels and inputfields, but the css is barely showing.

My question is: How would I go about applying classes and id's to this code so that the inputfields and their titles are shown just like the div elements I used previously.

**Previous code**

```
<div class="text" id="name">Name</div>
<div id="name_input">@Html.TextBox("Name", null, new { @class =  "textbox" })
</div> <br />
```

**Autogenerated code & my attempt to add css**

```
<!-- Name -->
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "text" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "textbox", @id = "input_name"}})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better to change the CSS instead of the razor . Try making CSS selectors by class and dont use ID like input_name.  Because @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, will create its own ID and if you explicitly change the ID using  htmlAttributes .. The input field will miss the server side validation.

Comment: This proved to be the better option. Much faster and much more flexibility. Cannot give you the correct answer since this is a comment :/